# XSLT strange behavior with umlaut (mutation)

Tags: html, xml, xslt, transformation

I have a very strange behavior when I got mutations in a node in xml when I try to parse it with an XSLT.

So we now assume that CustomerName has the Value 'MÖP'.

In this case, the resulting HTML 'a' tag would have a href to 'M%C3%B6P'

```
<a href="{CustomerName}">
    <xsl:value-of disable-output-escaping="yes" select="CustomerName"/> 
</a>
```

In this case, the resulting HTML 'div' tag would have an id 'MÖP'

```
<div style="display:none">
    <xsl:attribute name="id"><xsl:value-of select="CustomerName"/></xsl:attribute>
</div>
```

It seems like the attribute href in the a tag has something to do with it.

My question is, why is it like that ?
An what can i do that in both cases i got the same output ?

Greetz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XSLT processor is doing you a favour by escaping the URL value in the `href` attribute of the HTML link element. This is by design, see http://www.w3.org/TR/xslt-xquery-serialization/#HTML_ESCAPE-URI-ATTRIBUTES. If you really don't want that and you use an XSLT 2.0 processor then you can use `<xsl:ouput method="html" escape-uri-attributes="no"/>` in your stylesheet.

Comment: But could you also tell me how I could do it the other way so the id attribute value would be escaped the same ?

I'm working under .Net and in this case I had to implement the Saxon.Net Lib to transofrm it because .net don't works with XSLT2.0. When I could choose I don't want to use another 3. Party Lib.

Comment: No, id values shouldn't have that format.  
If you want them to be the same, you should try to turn them into character references (so MÖP would become M&#xD6;P in both instances). But I'm not sure how to do that with XSLT.

Comment: If you use an XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon 9 then you can use functions like http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/functions/intro/escape-html-uri.xml respectively http://www.saxonica.com/documentation/functions/intro/encode-for-uri.xml. XSLT 1.0 processors don't support these functions, with .NET's XslCompiledTransform you can use extension functions/objects, as documented in http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6datxzsd.aspx. If you need help with that then consider to start a new question.